# How can I put a progress bar in Shiny apps when I download my report?

Tags: r, shiny

I begin to develop a apps in Rshiny. I am a begginer in Shiny and am learning little by little this program.
So in my apps I want to put a progress bar or a message box when the user click on my button generate report. My report will be very long (15-20min for the download) so I want display something which say : Shiny works.
Thanks you if you have solution about that.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you try searching for it? Did you find anything relevant?

Comment: I am searching this morning and I found the showNotification tag of shiny. I think it's a soluce of my problem but the user will not know the time he must to wait.

Comment: Try [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html).

Comment: Thanks @Limey for your answer, I will try this in my render of my rmarkdown (when i click on my button DownloadHandler)